# Wordpress stop working - Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was working with wordpress and out of nowhere it stopped working.

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "rt_after_setup" not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:308 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-settings.php(601): do_action('after_setup_the...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-config.php(96): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #7 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 308

can someone help me ??

I try to reinstall wordpress, no works...